# Не отправляет данные в базу данных из формы

Tags: php, база-данных, post, phpmyadmin

Начал учиться выводить данные в бд. Целый день не могу найти ошибку, почему-то не отправляются данные из формы в таблицу бд. В чем дело?

```
`<?php 

if (isset($_POST['rating']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

$rating = $_POST['rating'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_user = "root"; 
$db_password = ""; 
$db_base = 'kt'; 
$db_table = "docs_reviews"; 

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);


if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
} 

$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (rating,name,text,email) VALUES ('$rating','$name','$text','$email')");

if ($result == true){
    echo "Успешно!";
}else{
    echo "Провал";
}

}
?>`
```

Comment: Загляни в конфиг my  

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Означает что NOT NULL - это не пустой иначе записи не будет
INT - это число иначе записи не будет  ИТД.

sql-mode=""  Пиши как хочешь)))  Но это не айс, чисти переменные и соблюдай кодировку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотреть что не так с мускли:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (rating,name,text,email) VALUES ('$rating','$name','$text','$email')");

if($mysqli->errno){
    print_r($mysqli->error_list) ;exit() ;
}
```

Если все нормально, смотреть что не так с `$_POST`. Если и тут все нормально, - смотреть что не так с формой.

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел ошибку с 

if($mysqli->errno){
    print_r($mysqli->error_list) ;exit() ;
}